trying to view webcam stream in locally hosted website using obs and nginx i can see it in vlc but the video player doesnt show anything in the websit
trying to view webcam stream in locally hosted website using obs and nginx i can see it in vlc but the video player doesnt show anything in the websit ive tried the code above and several other variation but the video player is always blank i can view the stream with vlc from other devices but idk how to view it in a website
<!DOCTYPE html>  

<html lang="en">  

<head>  

<meta charset="UTF-8">  

<title>Live Streaming</title>  

<link href="//[vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css](http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css)" rel="stylesheet">  

<script src="//[vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js](http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js)"></script>  

</head>  

<body>  

<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="360" width="640" controls preload="none">  

<source src="rtmp://[192.168.1.26/stream/streamkey](http://192.168.1.26/stream/streamkey)" type="application/x-mpegURL" />  

</video>  

<script>  

var player = videojs('#player');  

</script>  

</body>  

</html>

user  nginx;  

worker\_processes  1;  

  

events {  

worker\_connections  1024;  

}  

  

rtmp {  

server {  

listen 1935;  

chunk\_size 4096;  

  

application live {  

live on;  

hls on;  

hls\_path /tmp/hls;  

hls\_fragment 3;  

hls\_playlist\_length 30;  

hls\_cleanup off;  

}  

}  

}  

  

http {  

include       mime.types;  

default\_type  application/octet-stream;  

  

server {  

listen 80;  

server\_name [192.168.1.26](http://192.168.1.26);  

  

location /hls/ {  

types {  

application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;  

video/mp2t ts;  

}  

alias /tmp/hls/;  

add\_header Cache-Control no-cache;  

}  

}  

}


Hello, could you please format your properly?
